# Strange behavior if condition c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have this simple if condition, where count is always `> 0`

```
if((source - target) > (count * 10 /100)){
  .. do something
}
```

but I have this strange behavior the code execute `" .. do something"` also when the difference is < 0, why??

**EDIT**:
`source, target, count` are all `int`

Comment: A strong possibility is that `count` is of an unsigned type. That gets you promotion up to unsigned of the negative number, with wrapping. Simply SAY NO to unsigned for numbers (it's great for bits, not for numbers).

Comment: can we see what types the source, target and count are?

Comment: If the types are really signed `int`, then the only possibility for the `if` body to execute when the difference is negative, is when also `count` is negative. However, I think the claim is dubious. Why are you not presenting a reproducible example?

Comment: I deleted my answer, because it didnt answer the question and I dont know how to improve it unless you provide a [mcve]. If `count` really is `>0` and the difference is `<0` then the condition is `false`. If you encounter something else you have to show us the example

Answer (score 2):

Print out source, target, count. Then print out the result of (source - target) > (count * 10 /100).
Then you can determine whether you made a mistake. Or there is a bug in the c++ language(probability < 0.000000000000000000001).
Make sure count is signed.